# split each persons share in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calculation

I'm trying to write a program where group of people shares a bill, however each of the user has paid different amount, to sum up, i'm able to calculate total sum, and divide it into number of users in order to get per-person share.
and then I have two array which contains users who has to pay and who has to get paid,
I would like to write a function, where it can loop through users/lenders/owers and return who pays how much to whom

Please note i'm trying to write it without any mutation, it can be done with recursive function and/or reduce method, yet im not able to think of any solution.

here is the code i have come so far...

```
const users = [   {id:1, username:"John One", amount:50},   {id:2, username:"John Two", amount:75},   {id:3, username:"John Three", amount:100},   {id:4, username:"John Four", amount:125},   {id:5, username:"John Five", amount:150},   ]

const total = users.reduce((acc, user)=>{   return acc + user.amount; },0);

const calculate =  ()=>{  const perPersonShare = total / users.length;


  const separateUsers = ()=>{
    const initialLenders = users.filter(user=> user.amount > perPersonShare);    
    const initialOwers = users.filter(user=> user.amount < perPersonShare);
    const lenders = initialLenders.map((lender)=>{
      return {...lender, deposit:lender.amount - perPersonShare}
    })
    const owers = initialOwers.map((ower)=>{
      return {...ower, balance:perPersonShare - ower.amount, hasToPay:[]}
 })
 return {owers, lenders}   }   const {lenders, owers} = separateUsers()    }

calculate()
```

Desired output would be something like:

> result = [ {username:"John One", hasToPay:25, to:"John Four"},
> {username:"John One", hasToPay:25, to:"John Five"},{username:"John
> Two", hasToPay:25, to:"John Five"}}

any help or tips would be much appreciated..

Comment: Could you add maybe output example which you expects? From textual definition it's not quite clear what you actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: could you perhaps format the code so it isn't so .... random - e.g., it looked like you were declaring variables after a return - also, the results of calculate are not available outside of that function, so ... how do you know if it works or not

Comment: at the moment, your code produces `"message": "SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'const'",` because of that const after the return - maybe that's the only issue, that and the fact that you don't check the browser console for errors

Comment: I have edited with the output which i'm trying to get

Comment: `result =`  .... well, do that

Comment: So, basically you want to redistribute money across users equally?

Comment: yes, so the result shows how much each user has to pay or get the amount

Comment: Will it work if the `'to'` in the result will be an array of objects like this: `result = [{ username: 'John One', hasToPayTotal: 25, to: [{ username: "Johnny Two", hasToPay: 20}, {username: "Johnny Three", hasToPay: 5}]}];`

Comment: you don't do anything with `hasToPay:[]` - you've stopped before distributing the wealth ... like most communist leaders :p

Comment: @jsN00b sure will do, as long as i can get  the idea how to calculate without mutation, i should be able to adjust to my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've balanced the budget

```js
const users = [{id:1, username:"John One", amount:100}, {id:2, username:"John Two", amount:100}, {id:3, username:"John Three", amount:109}, {id:4, username:"John Four", amount:109}, {id:5, username:"John Five", amount:102},];

const total = users.reduce((acc, user)=> acc + user.amount, 0);

const calculate = ()=>{  
    const perPersonShare = total / users.length;
    const separateUsers = ()=> {
        const initialLenders = users.filter(user=> user.amount > perPersonShare);    
        const initialOwers = users.filter(user=> user.amount < perPersonShare);
        const lenders = initialLenders.map((lender)=>({...lender, deposit:lender.amount - perPersonShare}));
        const owers = initialOwers.map((ower)=>({...ower, balance:perPersonShare - ower.amount, hasToPay:[]}));
        return {owers, lenders}   
    }   
    const {lenders, owers} = separateUsers();
    // ignore code changes above - I just don't like messy code
    // here's the balancing act
    const balanceSheet = [];
    owers.forEach(ower => {
        const username = ower.username;
        lenders.every(lender => {
            const to = lender.username;
            if (lender.deposit) {
                const hasToPay = Math.min(lender.deposit, ower.balance);
                if (hasToPay) {
                    ower.balance -= hasToPay;
                    lender.deposit -= hasToPay;
                    balanceSheet.push({username, hasToPay, to});
                }
            }
            return ower.balance;
        });
        
    });
    return balanceSheet;
}

const result = calculate();
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please try with this input: `const users = [{id:1, username:"John One", amount:100}, {id:2, username:"John Two", amount:100}, {id:3, username:"John Three", amount:109}, {id:4, username:"John Four", amount:109}, {id:5, username:"John Five", amount:102},];`

Comment: @jsN00b why? Does your code fail to set up owers and lenders correctly? Or is there a bug in my interpretation of the data produced?

Comment: with amounts as 100, 100, 109, 109, 102 (so, the `"perPersonShare"` is 104) - i tested the code above. And I don't think the results I got were correct - or may be I'm mistaken and the results are actually accurate. Both `John One` and `Two` needed to pay `4` each and the last user `John Five` needs to pay `2`. This is properly determined. However, all the payments (4 + 4 + 2) go to just one user `John Three`. Thus, `John Four` who also paid `109` got nothing. I thought a fair redistribution would give `5` each to `Three` & `Four`. May be my thinking is flawed - I'm sorry if that's the case.

Comment: I'll check my logic

Comment: @jsN00b - yeah, typo - did `lender.balance -= hasToPay;` instead of `lender.deposit -= hasToPay;` - I won't try to explain why it worked with the original data though - i do know why

Answer (score 1):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to sum up numbers in an array
const sumArr = arr => arr.reduce((acc, itm) => acc+itm, 0)

// method to split the payments
const splitEmUp = arr => {

  // determine the average (ie, what each user needs to pay)
  const avg = (
    sumArr(arr.map(({amount}) => amount))
  ) / (arr.length);

  // divide users as those who need to pay & those who need to receive
  const payers = [], receivers = [];
  arr.forEach(
    ({amount, ...rest}) => {
      const diff = amount - avg;
      // populate either payer or receiver array
      // if a user made exact average payment, ignore that
      // user from further processing...
      if (diff > 0) receivers.push({...rest, amount, diff});
      if (diff < 0) payers.push({...rest, amount, diff});
    }
  );

  // helper method to update 'receivers' array
  const makePayments = amt => {

    // a running counter "pAmt" to track when payer has paid all dues
    let pAmt = amt;

    // result-array which will track who received payment & how much
    const res = [];

    // iterate over "receivers" array
    for (let ri = 0; ri < receivers.length && pAmt > 0; ri++) {
      // access the receiver object (for updating dues they need to receive)
      const rcvr = receivers[ri];

      // destructure diff (as "rAmt") and username for populating "res" array
      const {diff : rAmt, username} = rcvr;
      
      // "rAmt" is the amount receiver can recieve
      // "pAmt" is the amount payer needs to pay

      if (rAmt > 0) {         // receiver is able to collect dues
        if (pAmt > rAmt) {    // payer has more to pay than receiver can take
          res.push({username, pay: rAmt});
          rcvr.diff = 0;
        } else {              // payer has less, update receiver's dues
          res.push({username, pay: pAmt});
          rcvr.diff = rAmt - pAmt;
        }

        // update the "pAmt" (helps terminate the for-loop)
        pAmt = pAmt - rAmt;
      }

    };

    // return the result array
    return res;
  };
  
  // return updated "payers" array
  return (
    payers.map(
      ({amount, diff, ...rest}) => ({
        ...rest, amount, payTotal: Math.abs(diff),
        payTo: makePayments(Math.abs(diff))
      })
    )
  );
};

const users1 = [   
    {id:1, username:"John One", amount:50},   
    {id:2, username:"John Two", amount:75},   
    {id:3, username:"John Three", amount:100},   
    {id:4, username:"John Four", amount:125},   
    {id:5, username:"John Five", amount:150}, 
];

console.log(
  'case 1: 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, \n',
  splitEmUp(users1)
);

const users2 = [   
    {id:1, username:"John One", amount:75},   
    {id:2, username:"John Two", amount:75},   
    {id:3, username:"John Three", amount:100},   
    {id:4, username:"John Four", amount:125},   
    {id:5, username:"John Five", amount:125},   
];

console.log(
  'case 2: 75, 75, 100, 125, 125, \n',
  splitEmUp(users2)
);

const users3 = [   
    {id:1, username:"John One", amount:100},   
    {id:2, username:"John Two", amount:100},   
    {id:3, username:"John Three", amount:109},   
    {id:4, username:"John Four", amount:109},   
    {id:5, username:"John Five", amount:102},   
];

console.log(
  'case 3: 100, 100, 109, 109, 102, \n',
  splitEmUp(users3)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

**Disclaimer**:
This solution is relatively very barebones/basic. It is completely plausible that it may not work for a number of cases. A thorough testing for all cases is mandatory.